# How to add a tabbar to the frontview controller of SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for my side menu. and it works fine. But now what I want to do is add tab bar to the bottom, Remove the menu button from the navigation bar, and add it as the first item of the tabbar.

[image]

When click on the first tab item the side menu should come as normal way from theleft side. How I can do this with `SWRevealViewController`

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create Property and connect to tab bar button

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *BarButton;
```

then put in        viewDidLoad: methods

```
_BarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_BarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
```

I think its helping you

Comment: I will let u know. Still didnt check it

Comment: Are you connect property to bar button